# Delete core data items

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How can i delete all the data in a particular attribute in an entity i don't want to empty all the attributes in the entity here is what i have now which deletes all the attributes in an entity

```
 func deletObject(){
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let moc = context
    fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    do {
        if let results = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            for result in results {
                moc.deleteObject(result)
            }
            try moc.save()
            self.cart = [Cart]()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            totalAmouLa.text = "₦\(Int(totalHoursWorkedSum))"
        }
    } catch {
        print("FAILED")
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I want to delete `delivery` in the `Cart` entity 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIB0S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **delete** an attribute from the Core Data model, you can only **reset** the value.

`executeFetchRequest` returns guaranteed `[Cart]` on success, the optional binding will never fail

```
func deletObject(){
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let appDel  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Cart]
        results.forEach { $0.delivery = 0.0 }
        try context.save()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        totalAmouLa.text = "₦\(Int(totalHoursWorkedSum))"
    } catch {
        print("FAILED")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok will this reset all the values for delivery

Comment: I think the right question to ask is is there a way to overwrite data in an attribute